# Format date in a new MongoDB driver for PHP

Tags: php, mongodb

How can I format a date in new MongoDB driver. This is what var_dump returns:

`object(MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime)#152 (1) { ["milliseconds"]=> int(1467565836000) }`

When I try to access to milliseconds I get the following:

`Undefined property: MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime::$milliseconds`

I'm using a Yii2 framework.

Answer (score 5):

Since the object of the date is **$model->created_at**

```
echo $model->created_at->toDateTime()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

The result will be some like:

> 2016-11-10 16:20:10

Answer (score 0):

My formatter for Yii2:

```
<?php

namespace app\components\i18n;

use MongoDB\BSON\UTCDateTime;

class Formatter extends \yii\i18n\Formatter
{
    protected function normalizeDatetimeValue($value, $checkTimeInfo = false)
    {
        return parent::normalizeDatetimeValue($value instanceof UTCDateTime? 
                 $value->toDateTime()->getTimestamp() : $value, $checkTimeInfo);
    }
}
```